# Mule: DataMapper - CSV to XML Conversion , Final XML is not formatted with root element

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm new to mule, working with Matamapper which converts csv file to xml. I'm able to convert csv to xml . But the final output response is not formatted with actual root element. Please find my final output xml structure. It doesnt have root element. Kindly guide me . If this is correct, help me how to insert root element. ( Bcz i tried Set payload to insert the root element) it is not working correclty.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <employees>
      <name>jothi</name>
      <street>123, main</street>
      </employees>
      <employees>
      <name>Jane </name>
      <street>Main Street</street>
      </employees>
```

Also referred : [csv to xml: not sure the best way to do it in Mule ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301420/csv-to-xml-not-sure-the-best-way-to-do-it-in-mule-esb/15304483#15304483)

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DataMapper+Flat-to-Structured+and+Structured-to-Flat+Mapping - giving errors in datamapper

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading MuleStudio to 3.5 cleaned up a lot of the errors I was seeing using the DataMapper