# Can someone give example how to convert csv to xml in mule?

Tags: xml, csv, mule

I am new to Mule.

I want to do below things

```
1) Read csv file from local drive
2) Transform to xml
3) Write xml
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to convert and map a CSV to XML is use of Mule **Datamapper**
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference

But, this **Datamapper** is a feature of Mule **enterprise** edition...

Other alternate option is to

1. load the **CSV** file from local disc using File inbound endpoint,
2. using **expression-transformer** to **split** the payload into each column, store each column in a **flow variable**, ref :- [How to read CSV file and insert data into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911296/how-to-read-csv-file-and-insert-data-into-postgresql-using-mule-esb-mule-studio)
3. and finally use **XSLT** to create **XML** payload with **flow variables** as input .. ref :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer

In addition, you can also refer following links :- http://opendevelopmentnotes.blogspot.in/2013/09/mule-esb-csv-to-xml-conversion.html

[csv to xml: not sure the best way to do it in Mule ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301420/csv-to-xml-not-sure-the-best-way-to-do-it-in-mule-esb)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Smooks](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) Transformer for converting to XML

smooks-csv-config-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                      xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
    <csv:reader fields="order_no?trim,cust_no?trim,prod_no?trim,amount?trim"
    separator="|" quote="'" skipLines="0" rootElementName="orders" recordElementName="order" indent="true" />

    <resource-config selector="global-parameters">
        <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    </resource-config>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

in your mule config

```
<smooks:transformer
        name="csvToXmlSmooksTransformer"
        configFile="/transforms/smooks-csv-config.xml"
        resultType="STRING"
        reportPath="target/smooks-report/report.html"
        />
```

then create the tezt class in java

```
package net.pascalalma.mule.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.module.client.MuleClient;
import org.mule.tck.FunctionalTestCase;
import org.mule.util.IOUtils;

public class SmooksCsvTest extends FunctionalTestCase
{
    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "config/smooks-csv-config.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testSmooks() throws Exception {
        InputStream in = IOUtils.getResourceAsStream("test-order.csv", this.getClass());

        MuleClient client = new MuleClient();
        MuleMessage reply = client.send("vm://test-csv-to-xml",new DefaultMuleMessage(in));

        assertNotNull(reply);
        assertNotNull(reply.getPayload());

        Object payload = reply.getPayload();
        assertTrue("The message payload is not an instance of String", payload instanceof String);
        assertTrue("The report file wasn't created", getReportFile().exists());
    }

    private File getReportFile() {
        return new File("target/smooks-report/report.html");
    }
    private void deleteReportFile() {
        getReportFile().delete();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.mule.tck.AbstractMuleTestCase#doSetUp()
     */
    @Override
    protected void doSetUp() throws Exception {
        super.doSetUp();

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","IE"));
        deleteReportFile();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.mule.tck.AbstractMuleTestCase#doTearDown()
     */
    @Override
    protected void doTearDown() throws Exception {
        super.doTearDown();
        deleteReportFile();
    }
}
```

The output of the above would look like this

```
<orders>
        <order number="1">
                <order_no>1888852</order_no>
                <cust_no>21625</cust_no>
                <prod_no>02745011</prod_no>
                <amount>31</amount>
        </order>
        <order number="2">
                <order_no>1888853</order_no>
                <cust_no>21625</cust_no>
                <prod_no>02745011</prod_no>
                <amount>71</amount>
        </order>
        <order number="3">
                <order_no>1888854</order_no>
                <cust_no>21625</cust_no>
                <prod_no>02745011</prod_no>
                <amount>3</amount>
        </order>
</orders>
```

[Reference](http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/using-smooksmule-to-transform-csv-file-to-xml-one/)